# jqgrid append rows from xml

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using a grid which have editurl: "clientArray",datatype: 'xmlstring',              datastr: '<%=_xml_string %>'.

I have a button in my page , and when i click it i make an ajax call and get an xml containing new rows that i want to add to my grid.

Currently i'm looping through the xml rows and using addRowData for each row.

My question is how can append these rows to the current grid? I want the rows that are currently in the grid to still be there and append to them the new rows from the xml i get.

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example prepare an array of data with the new rows. You can add all the rows in one call of `addRowData` (read [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) for more information about different parameters of `addRowData`).

The things will be more easy if you would return JSON data from the server instead of XML. It is recommended for the most situations. Then you can just make **one call** of `addRowData` with the data returned from the server to append there to the grid. Optionally you can needed to use small customization of the `localReader` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#array_data) for more information)

Comment: I added the rows row by row, i had some problem later on when i deleted them. but it think it's o.k now. thank's!

Answer (score 0):

depending on the formatting of the returned data, you could use addXMLData, however you may have to manipulate the returned XML first in order to have it format correctly.

Comment: @user664408: addXMLData Populates the grid and not inserts the new rows to the existing grid rows.